# Does the fact that the TDZ is not written for runway 22 means there are touchdown zone lights only for runway 04?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, airport-lighting, jeppesen, symbology

Does the fact that the TDZ is not written for runway 22 means there are touchdown zone lights only for runway 04?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Jeppensen Airport Chart Legend](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/intro-USA.pdf) (p. 3) **all** operational runway lighting are listed.

So I assume RWY 22 has no, at least active, TDZ lighting.